# Espresso hasBackground() matcher doesn't match

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RecyclerView` with several `CardView`. I set background to `RelativeLayout` of cards in code like that:

```
layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.item_background_grey));
```

Cards with different drawables look like  that
[image: white_and_grey_cards]

I want to **check drawable** with espresso test.

I am getting `ViewInteraction` like that:

```
ViewInteraction relativeLayout2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.last_interaction_entry_layout),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withId(R.id.tab_last_interaction_recyclerview),
                                        1),
                                0),
                        isDisplayed()));
```

It works okay, when I'm checking text inside. But when I'm checking background
`relativeLayout2.check(matches(hasBackground(R.drawable.item_background_grey)));`

It gives me following error:

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'has background with drawable ID: 2131165305' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: has background with drawable ID: 2131165305
Got: "RelativeLayout{id=2131230886, res-name=last_interaction_entry_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=736, height=113, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@2242239, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}"
```

When I'm trying to check if there is *any* view with such background

```
onView(allOf(hasBackground(R.drawable.item_background)))
      .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I get `NoMatchingViewException`.

Also, tried checking color directly like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34053101/11845909), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47552123/11845909) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28743371/11845909), got

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.getColor()' on a null object reference
```